# Keep Bluetooth Turned on while laptop goes on Sleep Mode

Tags: bluetooth, lid

I just want my laptop to go in Sleep mode while keeping the Bluetooth turned on. Keeping the whole system on while the lid is closed, it drains battery pretty fast!! Is there any way to do so???

Comment: no, sleep means it's *not* doing anything, and you want it to *yes* do something: manage bluetooth (and presumably some media player/application/whatever that's connected to a bluetooth device). What do you need bluetooth on while laptop is asleep for?

Comment: Sleep mode shuts off all wireless functions - Bluetooth, wifi, cellular, etc. are all offline in a sleep/standby mode.  There's no way to override this at the Ubuntu level, only systems that are designed with this kind of capability have it, and that's a BIOS level option.  Most systems however don't have this because Bluetooth on its own can be pretty power hungry too and standby is designed to be a 'low power' mode.

Answer (score 0):

I can understand why this is needed and I have a similar use case.
I'd like the machine to sleep, but be able to wake up on keyboard or mouse input - and the machine exclusively uses a bluetooth keyboard and mouse. It's a media center machine for me - even a standard wireless keyboard would require use of a USB port and consequentially other hardware etc. which I don't want to mess around with. It needs to be minimalist.
Either way, I suspect if your computer can do this at all, it would be a setting in the BIOS settings, not in the OS. It may be that some BIOSs support it and others don't. Have a look in BIOS to see if you can find it. Mine doesn't.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).